# Is it possble to use Azure App API Service connectors without Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to play with Azure App Api service using DropBox connector. According to [tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/) Azure AD is used for SSO authentication. I'm wondering weather it is possible to do this without SSO and Azure AD using DropBox accounts + OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

If you provision the Connector from the marketplace and then create a new Logic App, the Connector will have an "Authorize" button which is direct authorization at Dropbox with your credentials. There is no AD involved.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No, that is not my case. Logic apps are declarative workflows for specific needs. What I need is when user tries to access unauthenticated API ihe or she should be redirected to DropBox(or other service) login page, to obtain OAuth token.

Comment: Gotcha. Client side authentication/authorization. This is not as straight forward today as we would want but it will improve in the future. We have some guidance in the making around it coming out soon.